# Pasch's axiom in the hyperbolic plane

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, axioms

**Q:** I am asked to show that pasch's axiom holds true in the hyperbolic plane.

[Pasch's axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasch%27s_axiom)

**Idea:** I was thinking of about a circle $\Gamma$ whose centre is the origin of the complex plane. $\{A,B,C\}$ are within the circle $\Gamma$ and $\overline{AB} \in K_1, \ \overline{BC} \in K_2, \ \overline{CA} \in K_3$ where $K_j \quad j= 1,2,3$ are normal circles on $\Gamma$.

For instance: any normal circle $K$ going through $p \in \overline{AB}$ cuts either $\overline{BC}$ or $\overline{CA}$ since $p$ is an element of the segment and not the vertices.

Comment: Do you need to **proof** it , or do you need to **show** it? For a proof you need to proor it from the axioms , (hint the plane seperation axiom, or mention your axioms), if you need to show it , what is your model? (easiest model in this case is one of the disk models or even a free model)  btw the bold bit of the axiom as mentioned on wikipedia does not hold in hyoerbolic geometry "If a line intersects one side of a triangle internally then it intersects precisely one other side internally **and the third side externally**, if it does not pass through a vertex of the triangle."

Comment: @Willemien well the exercise just says "show" so I am not sure but we always had to prove when it was stated "show". I took the disk as hyperbolic plane. So you telling me that pasch's axiom is not holding true for hyperbolic plane?

Comment: It all depends on how "Pasch's Axiom" is formulated. If it is Hilberts statement of Pasch axiom "Let A, B, C be three points that do not lie on a line and let a be a line in the plane ABC which does not meet any of the points A, B,C. If the line a passes through a point of the segment AB, it also passes through a point of the segment AC, or through a point of segment BC." then it is true. - -  If it is the Beutelspacher and Rosenbaum version (wikipedia's description 6-12-2014) it is false. (I never saw this description before, but you linked to it) to it)